# Python module "cx_Oracle" module could not be found

Tags: python, oracle, module, cx-oracle

I recently installed cx_Oracle module on my machine, in order to connect to a remote Oracle database server. (I have no Oracle client at my side).

- Python: Version 2.7 x86
- Oracle: Verision 11.1.X x64
- Cx_Oracle:Verion-5.1.2-11g.win32-py2.7

Then everytime I run my script, it fails and print the following message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I found a related post at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788937/error-when-importing-cx-oracle-module-python), so I am wondering if I anyway have to have an Oracle client at my side where the python script is invoked.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you have to have an Oracle client installed at your side.

From the [cx_ORacle README](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/README.txt)

"Please note that an Oracle client (or server) installation is required in order
to use cx_Oracle. If you do not require the tools that come with a full client
installation, it is recommended to install the Instant Client which is far
easier to install."

**EDIT** link to Instant Client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which is really helpful. Another question stands out after that as I moved my script into another environment where an X64 version Oracle is installed, the script failed.                           

I did some research and found that might be due to the fact that the oracle client is 64bit and the python version is 32bit.

Comment: The aforementioned issue solved, by having a "dummy" 32bit Oracle client, and set up the environment variable "ORACLE_HOME" properly to the dummy client path.

Comment: Yes, the oracle client and the Python must match in bits for them to work together.

Comment: also helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159566/cx-oracle-importerror-dll-load-failed-this-application-has-failed

Answer (score 12):

```
# - This import requires appropriate oraocciXX.dll to be available in PATH (on windows)
#   (Probably LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 on POSIX)
#     where XX is the oracle DB version, e.g. oraocci11.dll for Oracle 11g.
# - This dll is part of the Oracle Instant client pkg available here:
#     http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html
# - Also ensure that python, cx_Oracle and Oracle Client are of same arch (32 or 64-bit)
#
import cx_Oracle
```

You can find out arch (32 or 64-bit) for:

- python by just running the python in interactive mode on command line.
- cx_Oracle: look at the name of downloaded file.
- Oracle Client:

  - run the sqlplus that's part of your client package
  - start Task Manager and see if sqlplus.exe has "*32" next to it (=32 bit) or not (=64 bit)
  - if you don't have sqlplus, use `dumpbin /headers oraocciXX.dll`
- If you're using POSIX you probably would already know. Use `file oraocciXX.so`

Finally if you still don't understand here is really for dummies instructions:

- Ensure you've installed 32-bit versions of python, cx_Oracle and Oracle Instant Client. These could also be 64-bit, but must be same for all 3. Can not mix and match. Links:

  - [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) Lets say it's installed in `C:\ProgFiles\OraClient\11_2`
  - [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Python](http://www.python.org/getit/)
- Windows:

  - `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgFiles\OraClient\11_2`
- POSIX (Linux/Unix/Solaris...) <-- Untested..

  - `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/32bit/oraocciXX.so`
  - (64 bit) `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH64=/path/to/your/64bit/oraocciXX.so`
- run `path-to-python/python.exe -c "import cx_Oracle"` to test whether your setup is working or not.

  - if it prints
  - nothing: then it's successful.
  - `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`: then oraocciXX is not found. Setup the env vars correctly.
  - `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`: You have a 32/64 bit mismatch.

Comment: To check whether a binary file (dll or exe) is 32-bit or 64-bit, you could also use `sigcheck` by SysInternals. More info at [http://superuser.com/a/808127/283407](http://superuser.com/a/808127/283407)

Answer (score 2):

After having been trying to solve this issue for days, I found out that `set PATH=%PATH%:<insert Oracle home here>` did not do the trick for me. I had to go into my Windows XP system properties and append the Oracle home to the 'path' variable under 'System variables'.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet :-( but for uniquephase above, you may want to try to check the permissions of the .exe and .dlls to make sure they are executable?

So the steps I needed to do to get it working.

Unzip the instant client from here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

chmod +x *.exe *.dll (I am using cygwin).

For completeness, I couldnt get cx_oracle to install via pip using cygwin.

So I had to use standard dist python (non-cygwin) and installed cx_oracle via the windows installer.

Also, I had to add f:/opt/instantclient_12_1 (location where I installed the Oracle instant client) to the Windows path (via System->Advanced System Properties->Environment Variables->System Variables).