# How can I get the import cx_Oracle line to work in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I am on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine.  I connect to Oracle 11g.  When I start my Python shell it shows the following:

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I initially installed the 32-bit version of cx_Oracle for 11g.  When in the shell and typing 'import cx_Oracle' I got a 'no such module found'.

I went and uninstalled cx_Oracle via Control Panel>Programs and Features.  It did mention that not all files/directories were able to be removed.

I then installed the 64-bit version of cx_Oracle; cx_Oracle-5.2.1-11g.win-amd64-py3.5.exe (md5).  A 'pip install cx_Oracle' in PowerShell indicated that the install had been successful.

Now when in the Python shell and typing in 'import cx_Oracle' I get the following error: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

What might I need to do to get the import cx_Oracle to work for me?

UPDATE:  Apparently the Oracle client I have installed is 32-bit.  I've read that this could be an issue with this import call given that my Python and cx_Oracle installs are 64-bit....does the import call check what Oracle client I have on my machine, thus this error?

Comment: Is your PC 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: Do you have a 32bit or 64bit Oracle driver installed?

Comment: Try installing the 64-bit version. I've had issues where I've accidentally installed the wrong version (32 bit).

Comment: I believe your Python and cx_Oracle must match your Oracle driver. So, if you intend on using a 32bit Oracle driver, then you'll need a 32bit Python and 32bit cx_Oracle.

You could try downloading the 64bit Oracle Instant Client and set your environment variables to point to that and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: The 64-bit OIC will play nicely sitting beside the 32-bit full client?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538238/python-module-cx-oracle-module-could-not-be-found