# Python cx_Oracle: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, oracle

I have a 32-bit application running python scripts.
On one user's PC I get this error on the other I don't.

- On the user's PCs with 64bit-Windows there is the Oracle instant client 32bit installed.
- PATH environment variable contains the instant client folder.
- ORACLE_HOME environment variable is set correctly to the instant client folder.
- The app executable resides on a file server (no installation on the user PCs).
- Python and all used libraries and scripts are also on the file server (no installation on the user PCs).
- Other apps can use the Oracle instant client and connect to the    database (not via Python) without any problems.
- Other Python scripts within my app run perfectly and load libraries.

What could be wrong on that PC? Where should I look at?

(please note that I don't have access to these PCs and I don't want to trouble my customers too much with diagnosis tools like dependency walker etc.)

This question is not a duplicate of
[Python module “cx_Oracle” module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538238/python-module-cx-oracle-module-could-not-be-found).
I did everything mentioned in those answers and it still does not work.

Comment: You have to have an Oracle client installed at your side. You've mentioned that in the first point but are you using 32-bit Python and the 32-bit client?

Comment: Yes, everything is 32 bit except Windows (probably Windows 7)

Comment: It seems not to be possible to answer this question, so I post the solution as a comment:

Comment: With Sysinternals ProcessMonitor I found out that on the user's PC msvcr71.dll was missing (however this dll is not even loaded by the app process on my developer PC!). I copied it into the folder where cx_oracle is installed and now I am one step further :-) The next error the users get is an Oracle error (Ora-24315: illegal attribute type).