# cx_Oracle doesn't work on Win 7 for Oracle 11g Client

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I just downloaded cx_Oracle on its homepage (http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) and installed it with defaults.

However when I go to my Python console it has the errors like this:

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

My settings: OraClient11g and Python 2.7, Win 7

As I am new to both Python and Oracle, I don't really understand some of the helps online which are mostly written for Linux.

Could anyone please advise how should I adjust the whole thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install? Using `pip`? Using `easy_install`? Another thought: If you have multiple versions of Python on your system it is possible that you have installed it for a different version.

Comment: For cx_Oracle, I downloaded the binary from the website pasted above and then keep clicking on "next". Then I go to Python to type in "import cx_Oracle". Is there any step that I have missed?

Comment: Potentially of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788937/error-when-importing-cx-oracle-module-python

Comment: Thanks very much for this. My machine is 64bit, while Python is 2.7.6 (MSC v.1700 64 bit (AMD64)), Oracle is Win64 11gR2 client version. I thought that they should be compatible.. Tho not working still.